# Can Cycles physically mix colours?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, color

I was trying to recreate a so-called CMY cube, which is a translucid cube where opposite sides are coloured cyan, magenta, and yellow. When looked at from an angle, these colours mix, e.g.

[image]

(More pictures [here](https://mabysoshite.wordpress.com/2020/02/24/cmycube/)).

The naive approach (namely, a cube with different shaders on each face) does not work:

[image]

Is this something Cycles can handle? (I mean, in a natural/physically realistic way; although if this is not possible, a "fake" solution would be interesting too.)

Comment: The effect seems to rely rather heavily on refraction: in your first photo the far corner of the cube is visible from three different angles through each of the near faces. To model it, you'll need a refractive material with a suitable index of refraction, and a renderer that handles it correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do it rather easily. Just do what you already did (make each face a different color/material) - just make the material a Glass BSDF. Don't forget to turn the roughness down. You may also need to play with the individual IOR's to get the effect you need.

[image: CYM]

Answer (score 7):

Cycles is perfectly capable of this :).
Just use a simple Glass shader.

<sup>Standard *Glass BSDF* shader with default settings:</sup>
[image]